# I have an issue, and I cant figure it out.... Mysql COUNT() returns 0 but returns correct when run in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm sorry to have to post this, I know it seems similar to other posts, so I ask you to please bear with me...

What I am trying to do: I have a sql query that is in a function, the point of the function is to find if there are TinyInts of a particular value (1 or 0), I am doing a count, and need to just return effectively if it found  the value in the specified in the query. What should be coming back is 1 but I only get 0's back...

Here is the whole function:

```
//return count of VALUES
function getcountsroles($searchParams, $searchCrit){
/// does query, gets results, counts the number and returns that true or false
///this willbe used to show the dashboard user control more efficently.
// $searchParams == column
// $searchCrit == int 1 or 0
//should fetch back the count back from the query
global $db, $dashboard_message_users;
$count_Data=array();
$query = "SELECT COUNT(userID) AS countVal FROM roles WHERE ? = ?";
$stmnt = $db -> prepare($query);
if(!$stmnt){
 echo var_dump($stmnt);
}
$stmnt -> bind_param("si", $searchParams, $searchCrit);

if(!$stmnt -> execute()){
  $dashboard_message_users = "<p class='alert alert-danger'>The db query faulted.</p>";
}
$result = $stmnt -> get_result();
while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  $count_Data[] = $data;
}
$test = 'userID';
$value = (int)($data['countVal']);
 echo var_dump($test);
echo var_dump($searchCrit);
echo var_dump($searchParams);
echo var_dump($value);
echo var_dump($count_Data);

if ($value > 0){
  return true;
}else{
  return false;
}
}
```

The calling function sends the column to count the values of, and the the value that we are looking for. when I run the query against the database I get the correct values, I have tested with different columns and values (again 1 or 0)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as 'countVal' FROM roles WHERE isUser = 1;
SELECT * FROM roles WHERE isUser = 1;
SELECT * FROM roles;
SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(isUser),0) AS totid FROM roles;
```

the first one returns 2, the second is all the rows where isUser is value of 1, 
third grabs all rows... and the last one was a attempt to see if it was going work... but it still only returns 0 to the result... I have also tried to get the count of rows should be 1, either if true or false... This i getting annoying, Unfortunately I happen to be using mysqli lib and most exampled are for POD or old mysql_PHP, and in OO it seems to not like the prepared statements.

I am positive its something I am doing, I have looked over and over my code and I cant see what the issue is... Maybe if a fresh pair of eyes.

Any time or replies that help me and others out would be greatly appreciated.

Jesse Fender

Comment: `WHERE ? = ?`.... you can't bind column names

Comment: This is the result of the var_dump() for the assoc_array for $count_Data:
`D:\wamp\www\phpprojects\php6\model\Admin.php:494:
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'countVal' => int 0`

Comment: @MarkBaker => I have done it before, and it seems to work... Are you sure?

Comment: Consider what binding actually does.... yes, I'm sure. [The answers to this question explain why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter)

Comment: @MarkBaker => Im sorry - I just have been struggling through this ... Ill give it a try and write back...

Comment: Yeah it worked... it was the first string parameter, `$query = "SELECT COUNT(userID) AS countVal FROM roles WHERE $searchParams = ?";
    $stmnt = $db -> prepare($query);
    if(!$stmnt){
     echo var_dump($stmnt);
    }
    $stmnt -> bind_param("i", $searchCrit);` Revised query code, It still is ok with the variable but Yeah I feel stupid... But I am still learning - @MarkBaker if you would show that as an answer post Ill mark it as such. -- Thank you for your help  -- Jesse Fender